# How to send a DM to a user on another server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This code is designed to automatically send a DM to a user ID registered in the database at a specific time, but typically it comes to me and an error occurs when attempting to DM to another user (Error Content:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'). Therefore, my question is to know how to send a DM to a user with a user ID and to the server to which the bot is connected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What research have you done? What have you done and what isn't working? Stack Overflow expects you to put some effort into your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When I talk about bot name, I mean the name of the variable you set the prefix to (`client= commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')`, client would be my bot name)

In the rewrite of discord.py, you don't send messages via the bot. To send a message to a channel you use channel.send(), so to send a message to a user, you use user.send()

To get a user, use your bot's name.
Enter:

```
user = <bot_name>.get_user(<user_id>) # this is the user you will dm
print(type(user)) # this prints the object type of user, this is just to make sure that the bot actually found a user
user.send("msg") # this sends the message, and msg is the message content
```

Next time, please post code and what you've tried.